# как убрать черные углы?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Вывожу новую активность уменьшенного размера поверх старой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в drawable создал файл для фона в котором и округлил края. Соответственно этот файл подключил как background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ff33b5e5" />
    <corners android:radius="20dip" />
</shape>
```

Но остались непонятные черные углы. Честно говоря даже не знаю в какую сторону "копать"
P.S. Это не диалог, это новая активность с заданным размером с примененным к ней стилем диалога.

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_additional);

    int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.add_width);
    int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.add_height);
    getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

соответственно стиль активности

```
    <style name="AppTheme.AdditionalTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: добавьте код как объявляете диалог

Comment: Нужно PNG с прозрачностью на краях (альфа-канал = 0) в качестве фона ставить, а в теме общий бэкграунд для данного типа активити установить прозрачный (transparent)

Comment: @pavlofff это очень похоже на ответ. Опубликуете? )